# PS Console runs $profile script, but PS ISE and ConEmu fails with Invoke-RestMethod error on same machine

Tags: powershell, ssl

I have two scripts in my PowerShell Profile (CurrentUser.AllHosts) that are causing me to scratch my head as they give different results on what is seemingly the same console.
On Powershell (elevated) the scripts work with no problem whatsoever but in ConEmu (elevated) and Powershell ISE it fails with an Invoke-RestMethod error - see complete error below.

The scripts are

```
#Checking latest version of Git
function Show-GitCurrentRelease() {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$uri = "https://api.github.com/repos/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest"
    )
    Begin {
        Write-Verbose "[BEGIN] Starting: $($MyInvocation.MyCommand)"
    } 

    Process {
        Write-Verbose "[PROCESS] Getting current release information from $uri"
        $data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get

        if ($data.tag_name) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name = $data.name
                Version = $data.tag_name
                Released = $($data.published_at -as [datetime])
            }
        }
    }

    End {
        Write-Verbose "[END] Ending: $($MyInvocation.MyCommand)"
    }
} # Close Show-GitCurrentRelease
```

And

```
# Downloading latest version of Git
function Get-GitCurrentRelease() {
  # Download the latest 64bit version of Git for Windows
  $uri = 'https://git-scm.com/download/win'
  # Path to store the downloaded file
  # In this case it's saved to the temp directory for the session
  $path = $env:TEMP

  # Get the web page
  $page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing

  # Get the download link
  $dl = ($page.links | where outerhtml -Match 'git-.*64-bit.exe' | select -First 1 * ).href

  # Split out the file name
  $filename = Split-Path $dl -Leaf

  # Construct a file path for the download
  $out = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $filename

  # Download the file
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dl -OutFile $out -UseBasicParsing

  # Check it out
  Get-Item $out
} # Close Get-GitCurrentRelease
```

Running `Show-GitCurrentRelease` in Powershell (elevated console) I get the following result:

```
Name                   Version           Released
----                   -------           --------
Git for Windows 2.16.2 v2.16.2.windows.1 2018-02-20 13:32:41
```

However if I run the same command in ConEmu configured to run an elevated Powershell prompt I get the following:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At [HOME]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:63 char:17
+         $data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I get a similar result with `Get-GitCurrentRelease`. On PS it downloads the latest Git-installer to the TMP-folder while I get the Invoke-RestMethod error in ConEmu.
I've been googling the error and as far as I can tell the usual reason for this error is a mismatch in TLS version between powershell and the site the script is accessing. But this seems to be something else in this case since it works directly in the PS console but not in ConEmu which is just a wrapper/skin around a console - on this case (elevated) PS.

Powershell ISE gets me the same Invoke-RestMethod error.

I tested running $Host on ConEmu, PS and PS ISE and got the following results:

Result of $host in ConEmu (elevated):

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.16299.248
InstanceId       : fb8e89c9-7395-47ab-b732-a102da041999
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : sv-SE
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

And in PowerShell (elevated):

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.16299.248
InstanceId       : ec79dc29-4444-4230-a0ee-a2ead575903f
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : sv-SE
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

And finally in PowerShell ISE (elevated):

```
Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 5.1.16299.248
InstanceId       : 7180cdbf-50ee-4187-8fc0-ac0b230095fa
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : sv-SE
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

ConEmu and PS are identical except for the (expected) InstanceId and PS ISE has a different value for PrivateData (not unexpected).

If I could see any meaningful differences between the different consoles it would be easier to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

`Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`

is happening because PowerShell, by default, uses TSL 1.0 when the site you are requesting is using a later version.

To set your script to use a later version try this before calling Invoke-RestMethod:

`$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols`